# Link between RF factor in x264 and x265

Tags: h.264, h.265, handbrake

Are the RF scales in x264 and in x265 connected, or are they independent?

For instance, let's say I'm encoding a video with Handbrake with the x264 encoder, at RF 26. If I switch to the x265 encoder without changing any other parameter (and, in particular, leaving RF at 26): are both videos supposed to be "the same quality" because they have the same RF factor?